Search results for multiple tags include Staging Ground questions matching only one of the tags
When performing a search for multiple tags at once, Staging Ground questions that match only one of the tags are included in the search results.  This differs from the other, non-Staging Ground questions in the search results, which will match both tags.
My expectation would be that each item in the search results should fully match the search criteria, regardless of whether it is a Staging Ground or regular question.
Example
Search: [java] [c++]
In the search results, multiple Staging Ground questions are included which contain the java tag but not the c++ tag.  The second search result in the following image demonstrates this:


I think this is just how the search works, isn't it? You would need to adjust the query to search for [java] and [c++], instead. Just adding multiple tags is like writing multiple words: any single word/tag could produce a match.

@TylerH no, in search "and" is implied when you have [a] [b]. You can see the regular search results do have both tags. But the SG items in the list seem to do an "or". Moreover: Using "and" in the search field always does a regular search instead of a tag search - you can force a tag search with and in it in some ways but just searching [a] and [b] is actually performing a regular search instead.

@TylerH see [[tag:vugu]] which has one question. Searching [vugu] [go] returns that single question. Unlike [vugu] or [go] which returns 73k matches.
